# Classification ML for sports betting

Tags: machine-learning, classification, normal-distribution, naive-bayes

I'm trying to model the problem on my own and I just want to have feedback if I'm on the right track. Suppose I want to build a model that outputs the decision rule for the outcomes of a football (soccer) match intended as the class of a data-vector, therefore

$$
y\in\{1,0,-1\}
$$

where 1 is win, 0 is draw and -1 is loss. A data-point in my dataset represents a single match outcome of the past 5 seasons and is made of say only 7 features (i.e. $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,...,x_7)$) just to keep it simple

$$
x_1:= \text{match-week of the season} \in\mathbb{N} \\
x_2:= \text{home advantage (boolean variable)} \in \{1,0\} \\
x_3:= \text{win-percentage} \in [0,1] \\
x_4:= \text{draw-percentage} \in [0,1]\\
x_5:= \text{loss-percentage} \in [0,1]\\
x_6:= \text{standings points differential (points team - points opponent)} \in \mathbb{R}\\
x_7:= \text{previous 5-games win-percentage} \in[0,1] \\
$$

Now, as I said I want to derive a decision rule for my algorithm which amounts to deriving the posterior distribution through the class-conditional distribution using Bayes' theorem

$$
p(y|\mathbf{x})\propto p(\mathbf{x}|y)\cdotp(y)
$$

Of course the prior can just be the fractional amounts of wins, draws and losses in my entire dataset (which, supposing a soccer league of 20 teams in 5 seasons should amount to a total of $36 \cdot 20 \cdot 5 = 3600$ training examples) whereas the class conditional $p(\mathbf{x}|y)$ is the one that I'm supposed to estimate through model fitting.

My trouble arises here in how to perform this last task. Say that I think that $\mathbf{x} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{x}|\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\Sigma})$, then how do I choose the values of mean vector and covariance matrix that optimize my problem? Should I use a MAP/MLE estimation?

My second question is, say I don't get very good results with QDA/LDA on the above gaussian model, then what kind of algorithm should I use? k-NN or SVM? I read here and there that linear regression might work as well but how can it be implemented? Can a NBC work as well?

Thank for your time and to everybody that will help me here.